# "In" or "on" the newspaper/notebook

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

When you write something down is it **in** or **on** your notebook?

> I wrote it down **on/in** my notebook.
>
> Please, take notes **in/on** your notebook.

What about newspapers?

> I read the article **on/in** the newspaper.
>
> It was **in/on** the newspaper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content is **in** a newspaper or notebook, but **on** things that belong to the newspaper or notebook.  If an object is **on** a newspaper or notebook, it is a physically separate object that is physically resting above the newspaper or notebook.

> My picture was **on** the front page of the newspaper.
>
> My picture was **in** the newspaper.
>
> The article was **in** the newspaper.
>
> I read the article **on** the newspaper's website.
>
> I put my pen down.  My pen was **on** the newspaper.

Comment: Then why do we say it is on YouTube? You can find it on the internet. 
Also, I read the article on the newspaper's website. Is the article physically separable from that newspaper's website?

Comment: @Ghost — Your comment would make a good question, but might be best asked on ELU.  I expect that the answer derives from plays being put "on stage" (not "in stage"), then movie casts working "on set",  then live radio shows being "on the air", then television shows being "on the air".  YouTube is analogous to Cable Access TV, but is more recent than HTML/Mozilla/the World Wide Web.

Answer (score 3):

The preposition "in" is better in all these cases.

We write *in* a book, but *on* a sheet of paper.

Similarly, we articles can be found "in" a newspaper.

Writing *on* a notebook suggests writing on the front cover.
You could put a cup of coffee *on* the newspaper, otherwise use in.